# Processing (the Java visualization language): edge checking function fails when used with an array of objects

Tags: java, processing

I'm working my way through Daniel Shiffman's excellent The Nature of Code book and have completed simulating gravitational attraction and repulsion between objects. 
The gravitational force works well, but my objects fly right off the screen. I would like to constrain them to the drawing canvas. I am using an edge-checking function written in the previous chapter, and it is failing to keep any objects on the canvas.
I would love to know why.
The offending function is the last block of code in the Mover class.

```
class Mover {

  PVector location;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  float mass;

  float G = 0.4;  //universal gravitational constant

  Mover(float m, float x, float y) {
    location = new PVector(x,y); 
    velocity = new PVector(1,0);  
    acceleration = new PVector(0,0);
    mass = m;
  }

    PVector attract(Mover m) {

      PVector force = PVector.sub(location,m.location);
      float distance = force.mag();
      distance = constrain(distance,5,25);

      force.normalize();
      float strength = ((G * mass * m.mass) / (distance * distance)*-1);
      force.mult(strength);
      return force;
  }

  void applyForce(PVector force) {
    PVector f = PVector.div(force,mass);
    acceleration.add(f);
  }

  void update() {
    velocity.add(acceleration);
    location.add(velocity);
    acceleration.mult(0);
  }

  void display() {
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(0,100);
    ellipse(location.x,location.y, mass*25 , mass*25);
  }

  void checkEdges() {       // why doesn't this work?

    if (location.x > width) {
      location.x = width;
      velocity.x *= -1;
    } else if (location.x < 0) {
      velocity.x *= -1;
      location.x = 0;
    }

    if (location.y > height) {
      velocity.y *= -1;
      location.y = height;
    } else if (location.y < 0) {
      velocity.y *= -1;
      location.y = 0;
    }

  }

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  Mover [] movers = new Mover [10];

  void setup() {
    size(1000,1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < movers.length; i++) {
      movers[i] = new Mover(random(0.1,2),random(width),random(height)); //mass, loc.x, loc.y  //each mover initialized randomly
    }

  }

  void draw() {
    background(255);

    for(int i = 0; i < movers.length; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < movers.length; j++){  
        if(i != j){
        PVector force = movers[j].attract(movers[i]);  //Calculate attraction force
        movers[i].applyForce(force);     //Apply attraction force
        }
      }
      movers[i].update();
      movers[i].display();
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Processing (the Java visualization language)`. I don't know why that offends me so much :) Its like saying, `C++: Convoluted C`.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo :)) funny. at least Matt is being explicit because processing is an ambiguous term given the many options here on SO. (offtopic: hey, you're studying creative computing, that rings a bell ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be calling `checkEdges()` inside `Update()`?  If not that, then how about in your main code between

```
  movers[i].update();
  movers[I].checkEdges(); // check after the update and before the display
  movers[i].display();
```

Comment: Inside Update() it functions perfectly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking whether `location.y` is less than zero.

Compare what you're doing for X:

```
if (location.x > width) {
  location.x = width;
  velocity.x *= -1;
} else if (location.x < 0) {
  velocity.x *= -1;
  location.x = 0;
}
```

to what you're doing for Y:

```
if (location.y > height) {
  velocity.y *= -1;
  location.y = height;
}
```

Comment: I have changed the Y portion to mirror the structure of the X portion, but the objects still disregard the edges.  Will update my code to reflect this change.